# how to convert a comma separated elements list into space separated elements list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have list like this

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Desired output

```
[a b c]
```

i.e space separated elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print('[' + " ".join(list1) + ']')       # ---- > [a b c]
```

And without brackets :

```
print(*list1, sep=' ')     # ---- > a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

out = " ".join(list1)
print(out) # prints  a b c

out = "[" + " ".join(list1) + "]"
print(out) # prints  [ a b c ]
```